# Is it a good idea to replace Sodium Chloride (NaCl) with Potassium Chloride (KCl) for everyday consumption?

Tags: blood-pressure, sodium, potassium, rda-recommend-daily-allow

Increased sodium intake is linked to higher blood pressure, and therefore larger chance of developing cardiovascular issues.

On the other hand, increased potassium intake (within RDA, which is a whopping 4500mg by some sources) is linked to less chance of developing such issues. At the same time, potassium chloride is used in lethal injections, which is not true for sodium chloride.

Is it considered a good practice to replace cooking NaCl salt with KCl?

Comment: Cardiologists who tell their patients to use salt substitutes apparently think so. (Salt substitutes are just potassium chloride.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### From the context of your question I would say no.

Increasing K+ intake is alright but completely eliminating Na+ from the diet would be a bad idea.

In terms of the cardiovascular diseases like high blood pressure associated with high NaCl intake,cutting down NaCl from the diet(that is making the food less saltier) or increasing the dietary intake of K+ through K+ rich fruits or vegetables could prove to be extremely useful but replacing NaCl with KCl without recommendation could cause side effects.

As we are aware that hypokalemia (low K+ in the blood)  increases the risk but hyperkalemia (high K+ in the blood) too can cause the same.
[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_arrest)

### Why some salt substitutes are considered good

Salt substitutes having high quantities of K+ in the form of KCl and KI and little amount of Na+ are considered to be better than having only KCl as the main component.The former donot help to eliminate Na+ from the diet but helps to maintain a high proportion of K+ to a low proportion of Na+ also they are a source of iodine.

[Source](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/articles/salt-substitutes-heart-health)

### Reasons why the dietary recommendation for K+ is higher than Na+

The kidneys are very sensitive to high K+ in the blood and ECF  thus efficiently excrete them.

### Why not everybody should  have a salt substitute.

People with renal disorders, hyperglycemia, neural disorders should be on a diet strictly prescribed by their physicians.
This is because renal disorders and hyperglycemia renders slight hyperkalimia. The nervous system relies totally on the balanced levels of K+ and Na+.
[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_substitute)

> "...People with kidney failure, heart failure, or diabetes should not use salt substitutes without medical advice. A manufacturer, LoSalt, has issued an advisory statement[6] that people taking the following prescription drugs should not use a salt substitute:amiloride, triamterene, Dytac, captopril& other angiotensin-converting enzyme inhibitors, spironolactone, andeplerenone..."

### Further reading

[NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3692158/#__ffn_sectitle)

Dietary sources should prove to be a more better approach to increase K+ intake in a non-prescribed otherwise healthy indivitual.They include:

> "... All meats (red meat and chicken) and fish such as salmon, cod, flounder, and sardines are good sources of potassium. Soy products and veggie burgers are also good sources of potassium.Vegetables including broccoli, peas, lima beans, tomatoes, potatoes (especially their skins), sweet potatoes, and winter squash are all good sources of potassium.Fruits that contain significant amounts of potassium include citrus fruits, cantaloupe, bananas, kiwi, prunes, and apricots. Dried apricots contain more potassium than fresh apricots.Milk, yogurt, and nuts are also excellent sources of potassium..."
> [Source](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/002413.htm)

Comment: While your answer seems solid, would you mind checking spelling and using SE's markdown features as your answer currently is close to being unreadable.

Comment: @Narusan pardon where can I learn about them.Can u help pls ?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is a good guide for markdown. For the spelling: It's considered good style to include spaces after punctuation. I'll edit your answer this time, but I recommend learning about Markdown as you can easily increase the quality of your posts.

Comment: Eliminating all Na from the diet would be extremely difficult, bordering on impossible. And how does reduced Na intake relate to hypo/hyperkalemia? I don't understand the logic of your second and third sentences.

Comment: @Carey Gregory as the OP was asking about replacing NaCl with KCl and not about cutting down NaCl I completely focussed on that.But your point is absolutely correct I will surely edit to add it after sometime.Thank u.

Comment: @CATHARANTHUS I have edited your answer and fixed the markdown problems. You can accept it if that satisfies you or reject the edit and do it yourself.

Comment: I've found it difficult to combine enough potassium sources from lists such as the one linked to meet RDAs. Can you be more specific about the amount range that a dietary approach achieves, and what assumptions that relies on?